# Probability in the space of smooth vector fields

Tags: probability, reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Let $(M, g)$ be a riemannian manifold. Is there a canonical/usual probability measure in the space $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ of smooth vector fields on $M$?

Comment: What do you mean by canonical/usual? Where does this question occur?

Comment: I want to make sense of the phrase “almost all vector fields satisfy property P”.

Comment: Again, where does that occur? What's the context?